# What am I missing in this simple MVC application with the querying report table?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

This is the case I'm facing:

I do have 3 controllers as following:
a) MetricController
b) CategoryController
c) NavController

Before I go further, I better to share that I have a simple layout on View (HTML page) which consists of a column (on left) representing categories and on right portion of page I have to show a set of information. The information has to change base on selected category (report type) on left column.

MetricController is responsible to retrieve some information from a table (Metrics table) and it is something:

EDIT **** STARTS

```
   public class Metric  {   //just a class for IIS log
        //[Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string date { get; set; }
        public string time { get; set; }
        public string c_ip { get; set; }
        public string cs_username { get; set; }
        public string s_sitename { get; set; }
        public string s_computername { get; set; }
        public string s_ip { get; set; }
        AND MORE...

    }
```

EDIT **** ENDS

```
 public class MetricController : Controller {
        private IMetricRepository repository;

        public MetricController(IMetricRepository metricRepository) {
            this.repository = metricRepository;
        }

        public ViewResult List() {

            MetricsListViewModel model = new MetricsListViewModel {
                Metrics = repository.Metrics
                .OrderBy(p => p.Id)   //just few columns for now
            };

            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

NavController is responsible for navigation and showing categories (retrieved from its table) in left column as following:

```
public class NavController : Controller  {


        private ICategoryRepository repository;
        public NavController(ICategoryRepository repo) {
            repository = repo;
        }

        public PartialViewResult Menu() {
            IEnumerable<string> categories = repository.Categories
                                                .Where(x => x.Visible == "1" /*|| x.Visible == "0"*/)
                                                .Select(x => x.CategoryName)
                                                .Distinct()
                                                .OrderBy(x => x);

            return PartialView(categories);
        }
```

Now, I have an HTML page which shows off a left column populated with categories (or let's say report names in the left column) and need to setup and run a query every time user clicks on one of a report/category name.

One thing I know (feel free to correct me if I'm wrong) is that I have to work on CategoryController but using a code as following ends up to getting a type casting error:

EDIT: This is definition of MetricsListViewModel :

```
public class MetricsListViewModel  {

    public IEnumerable<Metric> Metrics { get; set; }
    public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }
    public string CurrentCategory { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryController : Controller   {
        private IMetricRepository repository;

        public CategoryController(IMetricRepository metricRepository) {
            repository = metricRepository;
        }

        public ViewResult List(string category)
        {

            MetricsListViewModel viewModel = new MetricsListViewModel {
                Metrics = repository.Metrics
                    .Select(p => p.cs_username)  <<<<<<<<  cannot convert 
            };
        }
    }
```

The error is:

*Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)*

This is my first MVC application and I feel like I'm missing something. I could use a constant list of report and use

```
@Html.ActionLink(GenerateReport1, action ,Controllername)
@Html.ActionLink(GenerateReport2, action ,Controllername)
@Html.ActionLink(GenerateReport3, action,Controllername)
```

but need to load the report names from a table. Any help is appreciated.

Regards,
Amit

Comment: How is `MetricsListViewModel` defined?

Comment: I did add that to the above code in EDIT section.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for adding the def for MetricsListViewModel 
I think what you are looking for would be something like this

```
public ViewResult List(string category)
{

    var viewModel = new MetricsListViewModel 
    {
        Metrics = repository.Metrics.ToList()
    };
}
```

Comment: I'm adding Metric class so you have a better idea what that means please see above.

Comment: @amitkohan, what does matric list view model look like?

Comment: I truly appreciate your help but I just did add the definition of MetricsListViewModel. As you see it is IEnumerable<Metric> so I think the reason I'm getting this error is because SELECT returns IEnumerable<string> to IEnumerable<Metric> right?

Comment: @amitkohan, thank you for adding the definition. think my edit should be helpful

Comment: it compiled but when I click on a category/report name it throws an error message as:                                                    ** The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MyAnalytics.WebUI.Models.MetricsListViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MyAnalytics.Domain.Entities.Category]'. **

Comment: @amitkohan: the view is looking for a list of Category not a MetricList. the question is becoming less clear as i am not really sure what you are trying to pass to the view.

Comment: OK, each category or let's call it Report has to run a specific report. let's say I have report1, report2 and ... when I click on Report1 it has to run query1 and so on.  In fact, I am wondering how I can have a switch() case structure to redirect user to a specific report after clicking on one of those categories/reports.

Comment: @amitkohan, this sounds like a new question to me. is this one answered? if so please mark as answered and post a new question. Ill be happy to take a look at it

Comment: No it is not a different one. I'm still hoping somebody would give me a hint.

Answer (score 0):

**Change This**

```
 MetricsListViewModel viewModel = new MetricsListViewModel {
            Metrics = repository.Metrics
                .Select(p => p.cs_username)
```

**To**

```
 var viewModel = new MetricsListViewModel {
            Metrics = repository.Metrics
                .Select(p => p.cs_username).ToList();
```

As, I have No Idea about your `MetricsListViewModel`.

Comment: I did add the definition of MetricsListView. It is IEnumerable<Metric>

Comment: Thanks for check on me :) No it is not

Comment: Is the issue still there?